# Control sensor: SainSmart TGS-2600

Tags: gpio, sensor

I've purchased a SainSmart TGS2600 Air Contaminants Sensor, but got no data sheet or the like.

[image]

Does anybody know how to connect this breakout to the Pi?

Comment: There is an LM393 on the board, so in total it could be a [schmitt trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said V to Pi 5V, G to a Pi ground.

A0 will be an analogue voltage output.  The Pi has no analogue inputs so you'll need to buy an ADC to make use of the raw reading.

I'm guessing that DO will be low until a pre-set pollution threshold has been exceeded.  It will then switch high.  You'd set the threshold with the POT on the unit.  You'd need to connect that line to the Pi via a voltage divider (pair of resistors) to cut the voltage level from 5 to a Pi safe 3.3V.

Answer (score 0):

V is probably VCC (5V), G is probably Ground, A0 and D0 are likely outputs.  A0 is probably analog output.  This isn't the same module, but might be some help:

http://www.sainsmart.com/wiki/index.php/SainSmart_MQ2_Gas_Sensor_Module